# funciones/condicionales

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, vscode

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de coding y me pide lo siguiente:"Definí la función sePoneLaOlla, la cual recibe por parámetro el string del día de la semana. Esta función retorna "¡Pongamos la olla, hoy se comen pastas!" si recibe por parámetro el valor "Domingo", caso contrario retornará "Mejor lo dejamos para el domingo" "

Lo cual resolví de la siguiente manera

```
function sePoneLaOlla(Lunes){
    if (sePoneLaOlla = Domingo) {
        return "¡Pongamos la olla, hoy se comen pastas!";
    } else (sePoneLaOlla = Lunes) {
        return "Mejor lo dejamos para el domingo";
    }
}
```

al ejecutarla me da error y ya no se de qué otra manera formularlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También puedes realizarlo así:

```
function sePoneLaOlla(dia){
        if (dia != "Domingo") {return "Mejor lo dejamos para el domingo";}
        return "¡Pongamos la olla, hoy se comen pastas!"
    }
    
console.log(sePoneLaOlla("Domingo"))
```

Si solo se validará una parte, no es necesario colocar el else.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me sirvió <3

Answer (score 0):

1. El parámetro es una variable que contendrá cualquier valor, no el valor en sí.
2. Como el valor que se pasa es de tipo cadena se coloca entre comillas.
3. Para comparar dos valores se usa el operador `==`

```js
function sePoneLaOlla(dia){
        if (dia == "Domingo") {
            return "¡Pongamos la olla, hoy se comen pastas!";
        } else {
            return "Mejor lo dejamos para el domingo";
        }
    }
    
console.log(sePoneLaOlla("Domingo"))
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y la explicación, me sirvió muchísimo <3